# What kind of toolkits have people written to complement or on top of statsd?

Tags: graphite, statsd

I am looking for tools to daily reports for graphite, better installer for graphite, better UI like graphine etc.

Answer (score 4):

The Graphite documentation contains a chapter with a list: [Tools that work with Graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tools.html). This is a fairly complete list.  I only have one tool other worth mentioning that isn't listed there.

[Obfuscurity](http://obfuscurity.com/) is a very good blog to read for graphite tips and tools. The author is developing "an instrospective dashboard" for graphite called [Descartes](https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes). ([Blog post introducing Descartes](http://obfuscurity.com/2012/07/Introducing-Descartes))

I haven't found any "better installers" unless you use Chef ([sample chef recipe for Graphite installation](https://github.com/heavywater/chef-graphite) and [another one](https://github.com/joevandyk/chef-cookbooks/tree/master/graphite)) but it's not really that hard. You can find lots of little how-to snippets around the web, especially in places like Github gists that give cheatsheet style installation instructions.  For example, https://gist.github.com/2628070 for Ubuntu 11.10 with Nginx.